# How to subclass an abstract class with 1+ args constructor using ByteBuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I would like to proxy [java.net.HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) which has one constructor: `HttpURLConnection(URL u)`. How can I subclass such a class with **ByteBuddy** without creating custom "Empty" class with the non-arg constructor?

```
 new ByteBuddy().subclass(HttpURLConnection.class)
                .method(ElementMatchers.any())
                .intercept(InvocationHandlerAdapter.of(proxyHandler))
                .make()
                .load(HttpURLConnection.class.getClassLoader())
                .getLoaded()
                .newInstance();
```

Currently, it fails due to

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: net.bytebuddy.renamed.java.net.HttpURLConnection$ByteBuddy$Mr8B9wE2.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
```

I would like to delegate a custom `URL` to that super constructor it is possible.

But if I create a custom class

```
public class ProxiedHttpURLConnection extends HttpURLConnection{

    protected ProxiedHttpURLConnection() {
        super(null); // <---
    }

}
```

and use that one in `new ByteBuddy().subclass(ProxiedHttpURLConnection.class)` it works fine. There is simple issue with a contractor, not quite sure how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a custom constructor and invoke a specific super constructor using the `MethodCall` instrumentation, e.g.

```
builder = builder.defineConstructor(Visibility.PUBLIC)
  .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(HttpURLConnection.class.getDeclaredConstructor(URL.class))
                 .with((Object) null))
```

By default, Byte Buddy immitates the super class constructors, you can therefore lookup a declared constructor that takes a URL and provide the null argument manually.

You can avoid this creation by defining a `ConstructorStrategy` as a second argument to `subclass`.